# Welche Präposition gehört zum Substantiv "Unsicherheiten"?

Tags: preposition, grammaticality

Ich schreibe gerade meine Abschlussarbeit und muss mir einen Titel ausdenken.

Ich wollte fragen, was dabei richtig ist:

> "Unsicherheiten für die Suche nach etwas"

oder

> "Unsicherheiten in der Suche nach etwas"

EDIT: Es geht um die physikalische Suche nach einem Neutrino und ich muss die Detektorunsicherheiten und die statistischen Unsicherheiten erläutern.
Also lautet der Titel sowas wie: "Unsicherheiten für die Suche nach dem Neutrino" oder "Unsicherheiten in der Suche nach dem Neutrino".
Was wäre denn der Unterschied zwischen beiden?

Comment: Ohne zusätzlichen Kontext ist das nicht beantwortbar. Was ist denn unsicher bei der Suche? Ob das Ergebnis passt, ob überhaupt ein Ergebnis gefunden wird, ob es besser passende Ergebnisse gibt?

Comment: Habe gerade meine Frage etwas präzisiert. In der Suche geht es darum, ob das Teilchen gefunden wird und ich beschreibe die Unsicherheiten (statistisch und experimentell), die bei dieser Suche auftreten

Comment: Beachte, dass guidot bereits "unsicher bei" geschrieben hat! Mir scheint "bei" sehr viel geeigneter als "für" oder "in".

Comment: Das ist wieder mal interessant: Dass  es Unsicherheiten bei den Detektoren von Neutrinos gibt, muss man aus einer Frage nach der Grammatik erfahren.
"Die Gesamtkosten für den ca. 270 Millionen US-Dollar teuren Neutrinodetektor stammen überwiegend von der amerikanischen Wissenschaftsstiftung NSF. Das Projekt wurde aber wesentlich von Universitäten in Schweden, Belgien, Deutschland, Großbritannien mitfinanziert. Das Bundesministerium für Bildung und Forschung und die DFG unterstützten die Konstruktion des Observatoriums.".https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/IceCube#Finanzierung_und_Kooperationen

Comment: Oder "über", oder "bezüglich", oder, oder....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ich würde bei der Suche nach der richtigen Präposition auf die Grundform *unsicher sein* zurückgehen:

> - unsicher sein *bei* der Suche nach etwas
>     
>   → Unsicherheiten *bei* der Suche
> - unsicher sein *bezüglich* der Suche nach irgendwas
>     
>   → Unsicherheiten *bezüglich* der Suche

Möglich wäre auch

> - unsicher sein *in* der Suche nach etwas

Aber hier hat *unsicher* für mich eher die Bedeutung *zögerlich*, *zaghaft*, *verhalten*. Das liegt daran, dass die Präposition *in* (ähnlich wie die Präposition *während*) die Suche als jemandes Handlung hervorhebt, deren zeitlicher Verlauf als unsicher beschrieben wird. Wenn es also um Messunsicherheiten geht, ist *in* nicht angebracht.

Als nicht korrekt erachte ich

> - <s>unsicher sein *für* die Suche nach etwas</s>

---

**Zusatz:** @Takkat hat noch auf die folgende Variante hingewiesen:

> - unsicher sein *auf* der Suche nach etwas
>     
>   → Unsicherheiten *auf* der Suche

Hier bin ich mir unsicher :-), ob *auf* im Zusammenhang mit Messunsicherheiten geeignet ist.

Comment: Eher als *in* könnten auch *auf* der Suche Unsicherheiten eintreten, oder?

Comment: Das ginge auch, aber dann wird nicht mehr der zeitliche Aspekt der Handlung (während / _in_ der Handlung) hervorgehoben.

Comment: Deshalb komme ich drauf, evtl. spielt ein enger zeitlicher Zusammenhang (*in*) bei der vom OP gestellten Frage (statistische Auswertung) keine so große Rolle. Im Zweifel ist *bei* sicher die beste Wahl. :)

Answer (score 0):

"Unsicherheiten für die Suche nach etwas"

eher nicht...

**aber:**

"Unsicherheiten in der Suche nach etwas"

oder

**"Unsicherheiten bei der Suche nach etwas"**

Beide Formulierungen können richtig sein. Es kommt auf die Lesart an:

*Um Neutrinos nachzuweisen, sind riesige Detektoren vonnöten. Der bisher größte und leistungsfähigste Detektor für diese Teilchen ist IceCube am Südpol. Die mit diesem Observatorium aufgespürten Neutrinos stammen aus den Tiefen des Alls, aus der Sonne und aus der Erdatmosphäre. Hier entstehen sie in Teilchenschauern, ausgelöst durch kosmische Strahlung.*

*Mit den bisher ausgewerteten Daten fällt der Blick ins Erdinnere allerdings noch etwas unscharf aus – es bräuchte deutlich mehr energiereiche Neutrinos, **um die Unsicherheit der Ergebnisse zu verringern.***

https://www.weltderphysik.de/gebiet/erde/news/2018/mit-neutrinos-die-erde-durchleuchten/

**Die Forscher wissen nämlich noch gar nicht, inwieweit ihre Messmethoden valide und reliabel sind. Und ob sich Neutrinos tatsächlich so verhalten wie sie vermuten.**

*Im Juni 2013 veröffentlichte die IceCube-Kollaboration die ersten Ergebnisse, die auf einen nicht terrestrischen Fluss von Neutrinos hindeuteten. **Es waren zwei Neutrinoereignisse gefunden worden, zu wenig, um eine statistisch signifikante Aussage zu treffen**.[3] Im November 2013 veröffentlichte die Kollaboration in der Fachzeitschrift Science die Nachfolgemessung, die als Nachweis von nicht-terrestrischen Neutrinos gilt
Sie haben also ein Problem mit dem Messgerät (Neutrinos) mit Hilfe dessen sie Aussagen über den inneren Aufbau der Erde wollen.*

*Neutrinoteleskope wie IceCube können auch Supernovae entdecken oder zur Detektion der Dunklen Materie beitragen. Auch gerichtete Strahlungsausbrüche (sog. Gamma Ray Bursts), die z. B. von schwarzen Löchern im Zentrum einer Spiralgalaxie ausgehen können, spielen eine Rolle.*

https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/IceCube#Finanzierung_und_KooperationenDarum müsste es heissen:

Daher müsste es eigentlich heissen:

**"Unsicherheiten bei der Suche nach Neutrinos"**